# How to simplify sqrt(x^2 -x*sqrt(x^2+4) +2) to -x + sqrt(x^2+2) in Maxima

Tags: maxima, sqrt

Under the following assumptions

```
declare(x,real);
assume(x>0);
```

how to simplify

```
sqrt(x^2 -x*sqrt(x^2+4) +2)
```

to

```
-x+sqrt(x^2+4)
--------------
   sqrt(2)
```

Comment: Try `radcan` and/or `sqrtdenest`.

Comment: I have tried radcan, sqrtdesant, ratsimp, and many other simplifications used in different seqences. As of yet Maxima seems to be simplifications-proof.

Comment: You might consider posting a message to the Maxima discussion list, where there are more people who might know about it. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss